# Map both tables in Many to Many relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5, fluent-interface

I am in the process of implementing an entity framework and code-first technique using Fluent API.

I already have a mapping for one table:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Certificate>()
            .HasMany( c => c.Employees ).WithMany( e => e.Certificates )
                .Map( m => {
                    m.ToTable( "Employee_Certificate" );
                    m.MapLeftKey( "CertificateId" );
                    m.MapRightKey( "EmployeeId" );
                } );
```

What I was wondering is if I need to do an equivalent mapping for the Employee Entity as well?

Something like:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
            .HasMany( e => e.Certificates ).WithMany( c => c.Employees )
                .Map( m => {
                    m.ToTable( "Employee_Certificate" );
                    m.MapLeftKey( "EmployeeId" );
                    m.MapRightKey( "CertificateId" );
                } );
```

or will a simple `HasMany(...).WithMany(...)` be good enough?

Comment: No you don't, it's enough to do it on one o the 2 entities

Comment: thank you.  What would the effect of doing it on both sides do?  Would it be redundant without any repercussions or would it cause a potential N+1 situation?

Comment: I've tried to create a db declaring the configuration twice, and it created the db as i expected, so the 2 configuration should coexist without problems. But personally I would keep just 1.

Comment: Ideally, that would be great but as the Table Mapping is located in the Domain class file, I may not be able to control whether it has been declared once or twice.  I migrated away from extending off the Model Builder and into a ClassMap design inheriting from the `EntityTypeConfiguration<T>` class.

Comment: Either way it works great.  Thank you.